# Looking for other possible ways to check if a variable means something

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

I've been trying to make a program that calculates the age of someone but someone told me I was doing something wrong.  Originally I had

```
if monthInput == "january" or "1":
    monthInput = 1
    validMonth = True
```

But apparently that would make validMonth True even if "bob" was inputted.  I was told that replacing the first line with

```
if monthInput in ["january", "1"]:
```

would do the trick.  But could I also do

```
if monthInput == "january" or monthInput == "1":
```

instead of that?  I'm just trying to see all my options (I'm still learning so this would be helpful for the future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can also do `monthInput == "january" or monthInput == "1"`. From a boolean logic point of view, that is the same as `monthInput in ["january", "1"]`.

There are differences between these statements, but they'll both produce either `True` or `False`, and both return the same output for the exact same values of `mothInput`.

You can try out what statements like these do in your Python interactive interpreter:

```
>>> monthInput = "1"
>>> monthInput == "january" or monthInput == "1"
True
>>> monthInput in ["january", "1"]
True
```

etc.

If you really want to dig down into this, the *best* method is to use a set:

```
monthInput in {'january', '1'}
```

because set membership testing takes constant cost (independent of the size of the set) where chaining `or` statements or using a list to test against takes linear cost (the more elements you need to test against the longer it takes).

Comment: Of course, *creating* the set in the first place takes linear time, so there's no upshot if you are creating the test simply to do a membership test.

Comment: @chepner: It is stored as a constant when compiled. It is created **once** when the bytecode is loaded. So do the `'january'` and `'1'` strings, or the list in the alternative scenarios.

Comment: `def f(): return 5 in {1,2,3}; dis.dis(f)` shows one `LOAD_CONST` per set element, followed by a `BUILD_SET` op.

Comment: @chepner: bah, humbug. That is a shortcoming in the compiler still. Off to the bugtracker!

Comment: @chepner: Ah, Python 3 has fixed that. It's just Python 2.7 that still wants to create a set from that each time. From a 3.3 `dis.dis()` result: `LOAD_CONST               5 (frozenset({1, 2, 3}))`. Python 3.2 does it correct too, let me find a 3.1 install somewhere.

Comment: Nice. I see it still in 3.1, but I admit that's an older version.

Comment: @chepner: See http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations, it is new in 3.2.